# What is the best way to create Azure devops automated release pipeline with Git flow

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops, git-flow

I have an application with .NET Core web API and Angular client application which is hosted in Azure as app services. Trying to introduce full DevOps practice to this up until production.

I'm trying to create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps while keeping git-flow as my branching strategy. currently,

I have 5 different environments which are **Dev > QA > UAT > Pre-Prod > PRODUCTION**.

I know with a trunk-based approach this is pretty easy to configure with one release pipeline which will go through all the environments as one release until it goes to production. In the current setup, this is automated only up to the UAT environment using Only the Development branch as the release pipeline which works pretty well.

I'm wondering what would be the most suitable way to do it keeping git-flow as my branching strategy. Also, relevant branches should automatically tag with UAT and production releases.

Mainly I have a development branch that contains the latest development activities and feature branches will be merged into development after PR approvals and Master is the production equal branch.

With my current environments setup, releasing this to UAT is quite simple with the Development branch but when proceeding to Production it might cause problems.

To keep the question short considering multiple factors, I was planning to have 3 different pipelines as follows

1. **UAT** - One release pipeline from development which goes through *Dev > QA > UAT*
2. **Prod** - Master branch will be configured with this pipeline which goes through Pre-Prod > Prod environments. this will be a separate build pipeline which will trigger soon after development merges with the master branch. this will be the main production pipeline. either this could be a master or separate release branch.
3. **Hotfix** - This will be the Production hotfix release pipeline with a separate build pipeline which goes through *QA > Pre-Prod > Prod*.

Will this approach works or any bettor way of doing this. Since this is the very first time planning release it to production through the pipeline. I would like to hear advice from experts?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. How did you eventually configure your environment?